# Spring Reactive with MongoDB fails for more than 1000 records

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I have two Spring Boot services, first one reads a file line by line transforming into a flux and makes a POST request:

```
webClient.post()
            .uri("/foobar/bulk")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(createFlux(), Foobar.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Void.class)
            .subscribe();
```

The second service receives a `Flux<Foobar>` and saves it to database:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@PostMapping(value = "/foobar/bulk", consumes = APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> bulkInsert(@RequestBody Flux<Foobar> foobars) {
    return foobarReactiveRepository.insert(foobars).then();
}
```

But only ~1000 objects are saved into mongo db and then it fails (in first service) with:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: 

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:151) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$createResponseException$7(DefaultWebClient.java:466) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:331) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1476) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:378) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:202) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:343) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:325) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:372) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:522) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:141) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
```

Not sure if it's important but in second service logs I can see around 10 lines like:

```
[ntLoopGroup-2-7] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:1424}] to localhost:27017
```

If I increase `maxPoolSize` param for `spring.data.mongodb.uri` I get more objects into database and more logs like above.

I'm using

- `spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.1.0.RELEASE'`
- `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive:2.1.0.RELEASE`

Have I misconfigured something or using wrongly mongo/reactive API ?

Comment: I, too, had made such API in the past. I too faced the same error but somehow even after showing the 500 error the updates were successful.

Comment: Instead of inserting one by one, try inserting in one go. Convert the flux into a mono of list of foobar and then insert that list into the repo.

Comment: @uneq95 I don't want to do that as I'm reading a huge file with more than 10k lines

Comment: Then update in batches.

Comment: See this https://dzone.com/articles/bulk-operations-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

actually all data was inserted into database but with the error I described. I changed a bit the code and now everything is ok:

```
 webClient.post()
            .uri("/foobar/bulk")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(createFlux(), Foobar.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Long.class)
            .subscribe(count -> log.info("items sent and received: " + count));
```

And the receiver:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/bulk", consumes = APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<Long> bulkInsert(@RequestBody Flux<Foobar> foobars) {
    return foobarReactiveRepository.insert(foobars).count();
}
```

Comment: Looks like a workaround to me and not a legitimate solution.